# How do i calculate the length of a line between two points?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Point variables.
Start and End.

For example the start point is 121,100
The end point is 140,122

And i drew a line between the two points. How do i find the length of the line between the two points ?

In pictureBox1 mouse down i did:

```
start = e.Location;
```

In pictureBox1 mouse up i did:

```
end = e.Location;
```

Comment: Pythagoras said it's sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 ) a very long time ago.  I'll let you translate this to C#.

Comment: You have not even tried to google this. Come on.. [here you go](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=length+between+line#q=length+of+line+between+two+points)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's simple maths formula **sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)**

```
Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((end.Y - start.Y), 2) + Math.Pow((end.X - start.X), 2));
```